# MarqueeLabel text won't scroll

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I want to display a label that continuously scrolls horizontally if it doesn't fit its superview. Kind of like on television when you have info showing up at the bottom with scrolling text.

I use [MarqueeLabel/Swift](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel) pod

- I created a sample project with a simple label that doesn't fit its superview:

[image]

- I set its class as a MarqueeLabel:

[image]

- I added some settings just as shown in their demo project:

[image]

- And finally added this in code, same thing, I copied/pasted it from their demo (sorry for the image this time I couldn't get the formatting to work on stack-overflow!):

[image]

Any suggestion ? My only doubt is that when I set the class to be a MarqueeLabel, it automatically sets the Module as "MarqueeLabel" whereas I would have expected it to name it after my project name : "TestMarquee"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem maybe is the fact that your label view is out of the visual bounds of the parent view, thus you might need to add constraints to it.

I suggest you limit the label with 10-10 constraints on the left and right side respectively, and center it horizontally and vertically.

This way, the parent view controller will be able to layout it properly for you.

Comment: Well I feel kind of stupid but this was exactly the problem! Will mark as accepted as soon as SO authorizes me, hopefully it helps other devs !